# Is there a situation where using a two-sample one-sided test is the right thing to do?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, one-tailed-test

In the context of health studies, I have to explain to non-statistician colleagues the difference between performing a one-tailed test at alpha=5% and a two-tailed test at alpha=10% when comparing two samples.

Indeed, being able to present a lower alpha for the apparent same statistical power can be falsely appealing for someone without the comprehension of the concept behind it.

In my comprehension, we should only use one-sample tests when the difference can "physically" only go in one direction ([CMIIW](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/CMIIW)). However, when comparing groups, I cannot figure out an instance where it is physically impossible for the value to be, say, higher in the control group.

Reading the numerous material here on SSE (the best one being [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/189354/81974) to me) further supports my opinion that performing one-tailed tests is hardly ever the right thing to do in this case.

However, when explaining to non-statisticians (or maybe students), I feel that giving an example of what would be a good use case of one-tailed tests will help them grasp the concept better.

Therefore, using the simple example of two-sample tests such as t-tests or log-rank tests, what would be a legitimate comparison case where a one-tailed test is recommended?

If the answer can be health-related, this is a bonus.

Comment: A chi-squared test is usually one-sided - you are looking for large values and you cannot get negative values because you have squared.  (In a similar way a two-sided $Z$ or $t$ test usually also looks for values which are large in magnitude)

Comment: @Henry You got me here. However, a chi-squared test is not what I'd call a generic two-sample test as it can have many more samples. I was more thinking about t-test or logrank tests.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say there are two treatments for a given disease, called A and B. You and your team are used to perform treatment A. Every nurse is used to it, all processes are optimized for it, everything works well. You really only want to change to B if B produces better outcome then A. There is really nothing in it for you whether B's outcome is equal or worse then A. Even if B is inferior by a wide margin to A that does not change anything. In that case a one-sided tests reflects what you want to know.

As soon as you consider writing a report and publish it in the unlikely event of B being largely inferior, a one-sided test won't do anymore.

Comment: "As soon as you consider writing a report and publish it in the unlikely event of B being largely inferior, a one-sided test won't do anymore." IMO this would not be a problem! The question at hand is suitable for a one-sided test. If later Aliens come and want to publish the other side, it really should not matter. You can re-evaluate the other side with a 2-tailed test. (+1 btw)

Comment: @KaPy3141 Ideally, the choice of one- or two-sided testing should be made before the data is observed and thus before the aliens arrive. Those aliens deciding later how to evaluate the data after having seen the data have all sorts of "researcher's degrees of freedom" and their $p$-values should always be taken with that in mind ;-) .

Comment: There is value in knowing whether you conclude that B is worse than A: it can suggest to others they should not investigate it further.   But if your small study simply fails to get a result either way then "further research necessary" remains a possibility.

Comment: "As soon as you consider writing a report and publish it in the unlikely event of" --> Are you saying that you should choose to publish a report or not depending on the outcome of the study? Wouldn't this be pure publication bias?

Comment: @DanChaltiel Obviously that kind of behaviour would lead to publication bias but I am neither saying you should do that nor am I doubting this is the true reality. What I mean to say is that for journal publication two sided testing should be the norm even though I constructed a decision making scenario where one sided testing would be acceptable.